# Improperly formatted CSV, how to repair?

Tags: wordpress, csv

I have a csv, and each line reads as follows:

```
"http://www.videourl.com/video,video title,video duration,thumbnail,<iframe src=""http://embed.videourl.com/video"" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no> </iframe>,tag 1,tag 2",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Is there a program I can use to clean this up? I'm trying to import it to wordpress and map it to current fields, but it isn't functioning properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Fix the program that created it.

Comment: What do you want it to look like once it's cleaned up?  I have often used Excel VBA scripts to clean up CSV data, since Excel handles the embedded quotation marks and other gotchas cleanly.

Comment: Just use search and replace in this case. remove the commas at the end and then replace the remaining commas with ",".

Comment: @Moshe Ah I dont know how I didnt think of this!!! Thanks :)

Comment: @Hikalea - You're welcome. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use search and replace in this case. remove the commas at the end and then replace the remaining commas with ",".

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone else have the same issue. Know that this solution will only work with data much like the example giving. If data has a lot of text and there are commas within the text that need kept. Then search replacing comma will not work. Using regex would be the next option and that can be done in Notepad ++

However I think the regex pattern depends on the data so not much point creating an example.

PHP could be used to explode each line also. Remove values that match a regex out of many i.e. URL, money. Then what is left could be (depending on the data again) just a block of text. That approach may not work if there are two or more columns with a lot of text